# How Variable declaration affect onTap Event?

Tags: android, flutter

So I was trying to detect gesture for my game app using InkWell class and I tried many way to make a gesture event occur.

After I found gesture event that work with my game app , I noticed that if I tried switching variable named mycolor which i used to toggle rectagular 's color as seen below to be declared outside Widget Build() . It worked !

but when I switched back to be declared inside Widget Build(). It didn't !

Why variable declaration affect the result for my gesture event ?

[Before declare variable outside WidgetBuild()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi6gE.png)

[After declare variable outside WidgetBuild()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZJMz.png)

```
class GameStructureState extends State<GameStructure>{

bool mycolor = true;
@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double w = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
 double h = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
 //bool mycolor = true;
 //debugPaintPointersEnabled = true;
 return Center(
   child: Column(
     children: <Widget>[
      Row( children: <Widget>[
        InkWell(
          onTap: (){
            setState(() {
              mycolor = false;
              print(mycolor);
            });
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(w/30),
            child: Container(width: 100.0,height: 100.0,color: mycolor ? Colors.blue:Colors.green,child: Text(mycolor.toString()),),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: Attach code please

Answer (score 1):

**WHEN THE BOOL IS DECLARED IN THE WIDGET BUILD:**

When your app first runs, myColor will be set to true.

When you declare setState() in your gesture detector and set myColor to false, it causes the entire widgetBuild function to rerun again. Thus, myColor is reinitialised and set back to true again.

So even after you declare the boolean myColor to be equal to false, when the widget rebuilds, it gets set back to true.

**WHEN BOOL IS DECLARED OUTSIDE WIDGET BUILD:**

When your app first runs, myColor is declared as true.

When you declare setState() in your gesture detector and set the myColor to false, it causes the entire widgetBuild function to rerun again. But this time, since myColor is declared outside the widget build, it is not reinitialised. So it isn't set back to true. Instead, it remains as false. And that's why your code works.